# Changing colours in Google Map (customizing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

Hi I try to change the colours of the city / suburb (word display) - words such as Sydney, Newington St. etc.
I'm fiddling around with the design but I can't seem to change just the word of the location.

```
  var styles = [{
                featureType: "transit",
                elementType: "all",
                stylers: [{
                        visibility: "simplified"
                    }, {
                        color: "#000000"
                    }]
            },
            {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "all",
                stylers: [{
                        visibility: "simplified"
                    }, {
                        color: "#282828"
                    }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road",
                elementType: "all",
                stylers: [{
                        visibility: "simplified"
                    }, {
                        color: "#000000"
                    }]
            }, {
                featureType: "landscape",
                elementType: "all",
                stylers: [{
                        visibility: "simplified"
                    }, {
                        color: "#000000"
                    }]
            }, {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "all",
                stylers: [{
                        visibility: "simplified"
                    }, {
                        color: "#000000"
                    }]
            }, {
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "all",
                stylers: [{
                        visibility: "on"
                    }, {
                        "weight": 0
                    }]
            }];
```

This is the javascript so far, this is how the design looks like!

[Current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4BvJ.png)

And I want it to look like this!

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qliji.png)

What do I have to change in order to make it look similar to the design above? I tried many things but they all look weird.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html: lets you style certain aspects of the map, then spits out json data you can incorporate into your map. Takes a little bit to figure out what does what but works pretty well.

http://snazzymaps.com/: find a theme that matches what you want